# Standard error of Weibull distribution parameter estimates

Tags: data-transformation, weibull-distribution

Hi I am new to R and I am trying to fit a Weibull distribution to my data. I
 see that the data has the following characteristics. To me it appears that the standard error of the scale parameter is very high. I tried gamma and that is also very bad. Could anybody give me a suggestion as to how to improve the fit.

```
fitdist(t, "weibull",method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))
Fitting of the distribution ' weibull ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
         estimate  Std. Error
shape    1.109726 0.003125828
scale 2278.465638 8.562804567
```

fitdist(t, distr = "gamma", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0),
        start = list(scale = 1, shape = 1))
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
         estimate  Std. Error
scale 1594.589975 9.651137871
shape    1.366665 0.006872685

Answer (score 3):

The standard errors of the scale parameters are small relative to the value of the parameter (they're measured in the same units) - the coefficients of variation are small.

If you used different units, both those values would change; it's only the relative size that says much.

I'm not sure I see any problem here.

But let's imagine those standard errors were relatively large -- that wouldn't of itself necessarily indicate a "bad fit". None of the information you've included is really sufficient to tell us whether the fit is reasonable for some specific purpose.